# Force create file from varbinary(max)

Tags: coldfusion, download, varbinarymax

I have a need to transfer files from one application to another using ColdFusion 9.  In application 'A' - the files are stored as varbinary(max).  The API for application 'B' requires a path and filename.  I'd like to be able to save the file from 'A' without interaction from the user so that I can pass the path/filename to the API for 'B'.

I've tried various cfheader/cfcontent combinations - but all of them require interaction from the user.  Is there anyway to automate this?

Both 'A' and 'B' are vendor packages - so I don't have the flexibility to change how files are stored or imported.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you!

Comment: By the sounds of it you want to simply be using `fileWrite()`. If you're doing this on the server, then HTTP headers (`<cfheader>`) and mimetypes (`<cfcontent>`) are irrelevant.

Comment: I appreciate the quick response.  I wasn't familiar with fileWrite() so I tried it but I can't seem to get it to work.  I get the error - ByteArray objects cannot be converted to strings. I'm not sure fileWrite() can handle varbinary(max) fields.

Comment: `varbinary(max)` is a DB column definition, it's not a data type in and of itself. You mean you want to write binary data to file? Did you read the docs on `fileWrite()` (http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-6cdf.html)? The *second sentence* of the docs says "If you specify a file object, writes text or *binary data*". So, yes you can write binary data. What you need to do is to do some research as to how. You should be able to google it in about 2min.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I was able to use cffile to pull the file from the database correctly without involving the user.  I was not able to find any example of fileWrite() working with binary data.  But it's working...so that's a Google for another day.